# previous state in reducers in redux with react

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is what my reducer looks like:

```
export default function catalogReducer(state = initialState.catalogItems, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_CATALOG_SUCCESS:
      return {
         count:action.count,
        products :[...state['products'],
        action.catalogItems  ?
        [...action.catalogItems['products']]
          :
          []
      ]
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

What I want to do:

1. This is a reducer for loading catalog items
2. Items are coming from a paginated api.
3. I need to add results from api to existing list of
   products

Problem:

I was hoping that state argument should would have the previous state associated but no, it is always getting value from initialState which what I initialize the state with on application startup.

Why is that? What is the way around for it?

Basically I need to have the complete set of items returned through pagination api and not just the products for a given page in `products` array. 
What I am ending up with is just the  array of products from last api call as `state.products` always gets initialized as an empty array

Also, generally speaking I am very confused about dealing with pagination api in react and redux and am not able to find a straightforward example.

A direction would be appreciated.

This is what initialState.js file looks like:

```
import cookie from 'react-cookie';

export default {
 categories:[],
  sessionId: cookie.load('sessionId') || '',
  youMayLikeItems : [],
  catalogItems: {'products': []}
}
```

//This file is to centralize initialization of states in the store

Comment: Could you provide your `initialState` please?

Comment: @IlyaLyamkin: Yes please. updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you need to remember that you shouldn't mutate state.

```
export default function catalogReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_CATALOG_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        catalogItems: {
          count: action.count,                          
          products: [
            ...state.catalogItems['products'],
            action.catalogItems  ?
              action.catalogItems['products']
              :
              {}
          ]
        }
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

You could find more useful examples [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html)

Also it's better to make simple states ([docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html)) without deep objects and use Immutable.js

Comment: But for some reason the arrays are not spreading out.Could you confirm why would be that.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? In this case we have one object `catalogItems` which contains `count` and one array `product` with multiple objects. If we want to have many `products` we need to change code

Comment: So if you want to have array `products` with many arrays try to wrap objects in array `action.catalogItems ? [action.catalogItems['products']] : []`

Comment: Hey, I have a couple of questions: 1. why are returning entire state object from reducer and not just catalog items? 2. I needed to merge products that were returned by reducer in last call with ones returned in current call so catalog project will iterate all products. the products are in products array inside catalogItems

Comment: 1. That's how reducers work. They should return entire state. But you can create several reducers with different states using [`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) to avoid big states. In your case you can create `catalogReducer` just for products items and `pageReducer` with `sessionId` etc. 2. I think objects inside products array should spread out. For now you can only retrieve products from current call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134295/discussion-between-ilya-lyamkin-and-simran-kaur).

Comment: what to do if we want to take a count of array from previous state?