# How can I get a previous state in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having a trouble while I was making simple weather app using react and redux.

I have two reducers. One is for adding data into an array and the another one is for removing a data from an array using find method.

here is the code :

```
// actions

// fetching weather api 

export const fetchWeather = term => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const res = await api.get(
      `/data/2.5/weather?q=${term}&APPID=132123123132`
    );
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_WEATHER", payload: res.data });
  };
};

// delete a list that matches the selected id

export const listDelete = id => {
  return {
    type: "LIST_DELETE",
    paylod: id
  };
};

// reducers 

// reducer that put a new data into an array

const reducerIndex = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_WEATHER":
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// reducer that deleting the data that id selected 

const reducerIndexDel = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LIST_DELETE":
      return state.find(city => city.id !== action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default combineReducers({
  reducerIndex,
  reducerIndexDel
});
```

as you may know, browser gives me an error saying 'Given action "LIST_DELETE", reducer "reducerIndexDel" returned undefined.'

I am able to fetch the data that I want to have but How can I make reducerIndexDel can recognizes previous state?

Comment: Follow this URL:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909566/previous-state-in-reducers-in-redux-with-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have written wrong spelling of - "payload" in `listDelete` function.

You are trying to access `action.payload` but it is written `paylod` there in action.

Comment: Exactly... I wasted few hours because of that small 'a'...  and add some few changes to solve the problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `filter` to get the state which do not contain the city with the id.

```js
return state.filter(city => city.id !== action.payload)
```